# Can not upload PDF file to Firebase Storage

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, pdf, firebase-storage

I need to upload a PDF file to Firebase Storage, and I works with my Simulator. But when I test on a real device, I get an infinite loading loop...

I searched for solutions, and read that I have to putData instead of putFile, and add a metadata.contentType.
I followed these 2 steps, but unfortunately it still does not work on a real device...

Here's my function:

```
func uploadDocs(docsArray : [URL], completionHandler: @escaping ([String]) -> ()){
    
    var uploadedDocsUrlsArray = [String]()
    var uploadCount = 0
    let docsCount = docsArray.count
    
    for doc in docsArray{
        
        let docName = UUID().uuidString
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("documents").child(docName)
        
        let metadata = StorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "application/pdf"
        
        if let data = NSData(contentsOf: doc) as Data? {
            
            storageRef.putData(data, metadata: metadata) { (_, err) in
                
                if err != nil {
                    print(err!.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                
                storageRef.downloadURL { (url, err) in
                    
                    if err != nil {
                        print("Failed to download url:", err!)
                        return
                    } else {
                        
                        uploadedDocsUrlsArray.append(url?.absoluteString ?? "")
                        
                        uploadCount += 1
                        print("Number of documents successfully uploaded: \(uploadCount)")
                        if uploadCount == docsCount{
                            print("All documents are uploaded successfully")
                            completionHandler(uploadedDocsUrlsArray)
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: *I have to putData instead of putFile* is not accurate and there's no reason to convert your file to NSData or use metadata. You can upload it directly as just the file. See the Firebase Getting Started Guide [Uploading from a local file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#upload_from_a_local_file). That code works - we use it all the time.